# What type of poison bait can I leave for the common UK wasp?

Tags: pests, insects, chemicals, wasps

I've heard that you can leave poison bait for wasps, which can kill a nest when wasps return with the bait for young to feed on. However I am struggling to find such products in the UK. I've also found reports that such bait only works on yellow-jackets, which eat meat, not on "European paper wasps".

Is the common UK wasp what Americans call yellow jackets, can they be targeted by poison bait, and if so what chemicals are suitable?

Comment: Alephzero  is right - but usually, most people in the UK just call out some local pest control company to remove the nest, if its a nuisance. Councils used to provide this service, but most don't now, since the tories snip, snip snipping, but it might be worth phoning your council to ask, especially if the nest is in the house somewhere.

Comment: Come on now, let's not get into politics here. I recall people complaining councils no longer offer this service for many years

Comment: It was just meant to be humorously observational, not political - I'm not really into politics, seems pointless, thoughmaybe you're right, maybe they did cut the service years ago.... we didn't have one here when I needed it 4 years ago, but we did 20 years ago, that's all I know.

Answer (score 2):

The insect popularly called "a wasp" in the UK is [European paper wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polistes_dominula). This is certainly not the same as the [Yellowjacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowjacket), the American popular name for various species of *Vespula* and *Dolichovespula*, which are more closely related to the hornet family than UK wasps.

The "conventional" way to eradicate UK wasps is to destroy and/or poison the nest, with DIY products such as these: [DIY Wasp Control Products](https://www.rentokil.co.uk/wasps/diy-products/) or for a large nest, by hiring a pest control professional who will have suitable protective clothing to avoid a massed attack.

The UK wasp species builds a new nest each year, and are unlikely to attack humans unless provoked. Unless they are causing an identifiable hazard (e.g. to pets or young children) they can usually be left alone, in the knowledge that they won't be back next year. The behaviour of hornets is less people-friendly, of course.

The most dangerous time for UK wasps in autumn - they feed on the sugar from rotting fruit, and tend to pick a fight with anything when they get drunk if the fruit was fermenting (just like some humans...).

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that's the normal route but I'm scared to go near a nest and where we are, likely to get several nests a year which would get expensive! The idea of poisoning the nests without having to locate them seemed ideal - but it's unclear if any products or DIY versions are available in the UK

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's an option. Wasps can travel long distances to feed. There's no real reason to be afraid of British wasps, but they are not active at night so going near the nests at dusk may feel safer for you. It depends what you call expensive - in my area (East midlands) the going rate is less than £50 per nest.

Comment: One thing NOT to try - don't attempt to sedate them with smoke. That works fine for bees, but UK wasp nests are made from paper, which is easy to set alight!

Comment: I am 99% sure the insect commonly known as a wasp in the UK is vespa vulgaris.

Comment: (I mean there are lots of things that are wasps, but the one most commonly encountered)

Comment: Have to disagree - hornets are the friendlier type. Speaking from experience, they will even tolerate humans close to their nests (or entrance, not directly *at the nests*, obviously). They may hover around and check you out, but won’t mind if you don’t scare them and remain calm. Wasps are a lot more aggressive and can be a nuisance if they switch to sweet food later in the season.